# How to change "number" attribute in ObjectListItem as per boolean flag condition?

Tags: xml, sapui5, master-detail, sap-fiori

In a master-detail SAPUI5 split app, I want to change the "Number" attribute of ObjectListItem in master list as per the condition of a Boolean flag...How can I do it? Kindly help. How can I control the 'path' value as per a flag?

Comment: Is that flag available in model?

Comment: I think easiest would be a formatter where you input your bool and do with it what you want ... :)

Comment: Yes the flag is available in Model . Thanks.

Comment: @zyrex : I am already using formatter to do some calculation  on "Title" attribute of ObjectListItem . Is it possible to pass multiple values in the Parameter of formatter function? If yes, kindly tell me how? Thanks.

Comment: I think it is only possible to pass one value :(

Answer (score 0):

you can use expression binding for this.

so something like this

```
<numberValue = {=${bolleanValueInModel}? 'OutputAsPerTrue' : 'OutputAsPerFalse'} >
```

If you want to do more complex evalutaion when value is true, I would recommend using Formatter to keep the XML code clean

Comment: Kindly give some example of Expression binding .

Comment: I added the example but somehow it was not showing before. Corrected it.

Comment: I already tried this one. But it prints all values in the output . I get following output -  True : 20    ,  False: 45  etc ... I don't want to print the Condition itself ! I think  there is some minor mistake in my syntax. i wrote following code --------------------------------------------------- number= "{=${boolCondition} === 'X'}?
           {
        path: 'OuputAsperTrue'
           }: 
             
          {
        path: 'OutputAsperFalse' 
           }">

Comment: It will be great if you can  give an example . Thanks.